# Can't expand Cocoapod on CocoaPods website

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I have created my first CocoaPod and published it. On the website, I am able to search and find it, but I am not able to expand. Instead of an expand button, I have 3 buttons - Site, Docs, and Spec.  Clicking on the link takes me directly to the Github page, instead of a documentation page within Cocoapods.org.

[image]

Here is my podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
s.name             = 'SpinWheelControl'
s.version          = '0.1.1'
s.summary          = 'An inertial spinning wheel UI control that allows selection of an item.'

s.description      = <<-DESC
                    'Spin Wheel Control is a wheel of fortune-style inertial spinning wheel UI control that allows selection of an item. It is written in the Swift programming language and to be used in iOS apps. The code is a Swift derivation, port, and enhancement based loosely on the Objective-C SMWheelControl CocoaPod written by Cesare Rocchi and Simone Civetta found at https://cocoapods.org/pods/SMWheelControl.'
DESC

s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/joshdhenry/SpinWheelControl'
s.license          = 'BSD 3-Clause'
s.author           = { 'Josh Henry' => 'MyEmail@MyEmail.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/joshdhenry/SpinWheelControl.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

s.ios.deployment_target = '10.3'
s.source_files = 'SpinWheelControl/*.{swift,h,m}'

end
```

I've followed this [this](http://orta.io/rebase/why-cant-i-expand/) guide and even tried to upload a new version with a revised podspec, but I am still having this problem.  How do I make it so that clicking on the Cocoapod takes me to a documentation page, not the Github page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 5 days later, the Expand option now displays and CocoaDocs have been generated. I don't think this was because of a change I made, rather I think it was because of something updating on Cocoapods.org's servers. Works great now!